# Using Numpy's readtxt to read Hex numbers

Tags: python, file, numpy, text

I am only able to read integer values from a text file, but when I try to read integers in Hex format, an error occurs. The code line I'm using is

```
output = np.loadtxt(fidOut, dtype="int32", delimiter="\n");
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add a converters so that numpy understands how to interpret the hex-data.

For a simple file `test.csv` with data as follows:

```
af,2b,10    
3aaa,4a,fa
```

You would need to specify converters for all three columns:

```
In [2]: np.loadtxt("test.csv", dtype='int32', delimiter=',', converters={_:lambda s: int(s, 16) for _ in range(3)})
Out[2]: 
array([[  175,    43,    16],
       [15018,    74,   250]], dtype=int32)
```

The dictionary supplied has column-index as keys and converters as values.
Depending on how your hex-data is represented in the file you may need to modify the `lambda`-expression above.

Comment: I really never used lambda expressions, although I know what they are. I guess I'll delve into that.. Thanks