# How to load file.npy into a numpy array?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, scipy

I've got a data like this:

```
934e,554d,5059,0100,4600,7b27,6465,7363
7227,3a20,273c,6938,272c,2027,666f,7274
7261,6e5f,6f72,6465,7227,3a20,4661,6c73
652c,2027,7368,6170,6527,3a20,2831,3030
3030,302c,292c,207d,2020,2020,2020,200a
2e03,0000,0000,0000,6f01,0000,0000,0000
0f00,0000,0000,0000,6202,0000,0000,0000
1c00,0000,0000,0000,2402,0000,0000,0000
7302,0000,0000,0000,3001,0000,0000,0000
9c00,0000,0000,0000,9002,0000,0000,0000
1302,0000,0000,0000,9301,0000,0000,0000
```

How can I load it to numpy array? I've tried follow the documentation, but nothing was helpful! I've converted this data to txt file and after each, the write like this:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt('data.txt', delimiter=",")
print(data)
```

but it results in an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cow13/Documents/Assignment5/datastr.py", line 2, in <module>
    data = np.loadtxt('data.txt', delimiter=",")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1024, in loadtxt
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 725, in floatconv
    return float(x)
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 934e
```

Comment: Your data is actually hexadecimal...

Comment: You should load your data as hex, because when trying to load as text, with `np.loadtxt`, by default it doesn't look to hex values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Numpy's readtxt to read Hex numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31344892/using-numpys-readtxt-to-read-hex-numbers)

Comment: hey, I tried your variant, but still didn't work;

Comment: import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt("data.txt", dtype='int32', delimiter=',', converters=({data :lambda s: int(s, 16) for data in range(3)})

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: `np.loadtxt("data.txt", dtype='int32', delimiter=',', converters={_:lambda s: int(s, 16) for _ in range(8)})`